# (NOLOCK) vs NOLOCK

Tags: sql-server, syntax, nolock

I was investigating some blocking when I saw a query that looked something like this:

```
SELECT SomeField FROM SomeTable NOLOCK
```

I saw the `NOLOCK` and was curious how it could be blocking other queries, in this case `DELETE` statements.  I took a quick look at the locks using `sp_lock` and here is what I saw:

```
DB      S   GRANT

TAB     IS  GRANT

PAG    S    GRANT
```

Now, my understanding is that `NOLOCK` is supposed to only take a Schema-Stability lock, why was it then grabbing an IS lock?

My curiosity was piqued.  I looked in BOL and saw there were two ways to use it, `WITH (NOLOCK)` and the deprecated `(NOLOCK)`, so I decided to give those a try.  I ran the following queries followed up by running `sp_lock`:

```
SELECT SomeField FROM SomeTable WITH (NOLOCK)
```

```
DB     S       GRANT

TAB     Sch-S   GRANT
```

```
SELECT SomeField FROM SomeTable (NOLOCK)
```

```
DB      S       GRANT

TAB     Sch-S   GRANT
```

Sure enough, there are my Schema-Stability locks.  So my question is this: what’s going on here?  If the accepted syntax for using NOLOCK is either `WITH (NOLOCK)` or `(NOLOCK)`, then why doesn’t the query error out when it runs with just plain `NOLOCK` (without the parentheses)?  If it is supported, why is grabbing an IS lock?  What am I missing here?  I’ve been searching online for an answer, but so far have come up short.

I’ve tested this on both 2008R2 and 2012.

Comment: `SELECT SomeField FROM SomeTable NOLOCK (NOLOCK)` for double nolock effect ;)

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52848/1186

Comment: The article describing differences https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-the-impact-of-nolock-and-with-nolock-table-hints-in-sql-server/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112855/withnolock-or-nolock-is-there-a-difference

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
SELECT SomeField
FROM   SomeTable NOLOCK
```

means you've just aliased `SomeTable AS NOLOCK`. Try the below to see this clearly:

```
SELECT NOLOCK.SomeField
FROM   SomeTable NOLOCK
```

This obviously has no effect on the locking behaviour of the query. The query doesn't fail because despite being a keyword & showing blue in SSMS, NOLOCK is not a *reserved* word in Transact-SQL and therefore does not cause a syntax error. List of reserved words: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

Correct syntax for using as a hint:

- `(NOLOCK)` is valid but deprecated.
- `WITH (NOLOCK)` is the recommended syntax.

Comment: Wow, not sure how I didn't figure that out.  It was really driving me crazy, now I just feel embarrassed:)  It's the simplest things sometimes, I guess.

Comment: @Brian No worries, I had to debug something very similar recently, otherwise it may not have been so easy to spot! You can see why MS have deprecated that syntax.

Comment: Is NOLOCK not a reserved keyword? Shouldn't it complain if you don't use [NOLOCK]?

Comment: Nope https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx Although it does appear in blue in SSMS which can throw you off.

Comment: Nice catch, LOL.  My favorite Q/A today.

Comment: For bit of fun with this: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/02/im-just-saying-valid-t-sql-syntax-thats/